# ARM NXP LPC1114 current sink source capabilities

Tags: microcontroller, arm, io

Can anyone help me to find out the limits of NXP LPC1114 GPIO current sink and source capabilities?

After reading the manual and the product datasheet I could not find this information anywhere. Also searching on Google I could not find anything.

All I could find is information about the high current sink capabilities of I2C pins.

Answer (score 2):

The info you want is on Table 16 on the [LPC111X datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC111X.pdf).    It depends on whether you're using a "Standard Port Pin", which allows a handful of mA, or a "High Drive Output Pin", which allows about 12 mA, all dependent on Vdd levels.

Comment: The amount of current that a Standard Port Pin can sink (when it's in low state) is which parameter?

Comment: I_OL on page 62, minimum (which is what you design to) of 3mA